# Won't recognize application delegate

Tags: ios, xcode

I started a project and compiled it fine.  Then I deleted (removed references) the AppDelegate class.  I then added another class GuardianX3DAppDelegate, in main changed:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
```

to:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"GuardianX3DAppDelegate");
```

Then I added the file to the build phases compile area.  I am getting:

```
Unable to instantiate the UIApplication delegate instance. No class named GuardianX3DAppDelegate.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check to see if `GuardianX3DAppDelegate.m` is being compiled, and/or sanity check by messaging it (e.g. create a class method which logs something) before calling `UIApplicationMain`.

Comment: Thanks. That was more or less the problem.